# Terraform - Upload file to S3 on every apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need to upload a folder to S3 Bucket. But when I apply for the first time. It just uploads. But I have two problems here:

1. uploaded version outputs as null. I would expect some version_id like 1, 2, 3
2. When running `terraform apply` again, it says `Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed`. I would expect to upload all the times when I run `terraform apply` and create a new version.

What am I doing wrong? Here is my Terraform config:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  bucket = "my_bucket_name"

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "file_upload" {
  bucket = "my_bucket"
  key    = "my_bucket_key"
  source = "my_files.zip"
}

output "my_bucket_file_version" {
  value = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.file_upload.version_id}"
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but can you try using this : https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/archive/d/archive_file.html to generate the zip file if possible. Just check if terraform recognize this new zip file as a changed file and upload the new zip file (which contains the same content)again with new version id.

Comment: The behaviour is consistent with versioning not being enabled on the bucket. Can you check to see if it really is?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Terraform only makes changes to the remote objects when it detects a difference between the configuration and the remote object attributes. In the configuration as you've written it so far, the configuration includes only the filename. It includes nothing about the content of the file, so Terraform can't react to the file changing.

To make subsequent changes, there are a few options:

- You could use a different local filename for each new version.
- You could use a different remote object path for each new version.
- You can use the object etag to let Terraform recognize when the content has changed, regardless of the local filename or object path.

The final of these seems closest to what you want in this case. To do that, add the `etag` argument and set it to be an MD5 hash of the file:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "file_upload" {
  bucket = "my_bucket"
  key    = "my_bucket_key"
  source = "${path.module}/my_files.zip"
  etag   = "${filemd5("${path.module}/my_files.zip")}"
}
```

With that extra argument in place, Terraform will detect when the MD5 hash of the file on disk is different than that stored remotely in S3 and will plan to update the object accordingly.

---

(I'm not sure what's going on with `version_id`. It should work as long as versioning is enabled on the bucket.)

Comment: At the time of writing (**Terraform 4.52.0**) there is a warning to replace `aws_s3_bucket_object` with `aws_s3_object`. The answer is otherwise the same. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/4.52.0/docs/resources/s3_object

Answer (score 16):

The preferred solution is now to use the `source_hash` property. Note that `aws_s3_bucket_object` has been replaced by `aws_s3_object`.

```
locals {
  object_source = "${path.module}/my_files.zip"
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "file_upload" {
  bucket      = "my_bucket"
  key         = "my_bucket_key"
  source      = local.object_source
  source_hash = filemd5(local.object_source)
}
```

Note that `etag` can have issues when encryption is used.

Answer (score -6):

You shouldn't be using Terraform to do this. Terraform is supposed to orchestrate and provision your infrastructure and its configuration, not files. That said, terraform is not aware of changes on your files. Unless you change their names, terraform will not update the state.

Also, it is better to use `local-exec` to do that. Something like:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my-bucket" {
# ...

  provisioner "local-exec" {
     command = "aws s3 cp path_to_my_file ${aws_s3_bucket.my-bucket.id}"
  }
}
```

Comment: S3 is often used to store deployment bundles that are referenced in the infrastructure definition, such as in Lambda or Kinesis Analytics for Java. This use of S3 is completely in line with "infrastructure and its configuration", which is why Terraform has a resource for it and why you *should* be using Terraform to upload certain files to S3.

Comment: I understand and aggress to the comment from @meustrus but aws_s3_bucket_object is now deprecated in favor of aws_s3_object which is only for reading file. I guess TF team is aligning with Stargazer on this.

Comment: They're probably right about S3 @Gomsy . In the past couple of years, I've experienced problems with S3 objects and related resources being fully updated before Terraform allows the dependency to be satisfied. There may be some issues with eventual consistency that prevent S3 objects from meeting Terraform's resource requirements.

Comment: `aws_s3_object` is not read-only. The docs give an example of uploading a file.

Comment: As explained in the official documentation, local-exec should be used as a last resort. Therefore the answer by Martin is much more reasonable.
https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec