# Uploading Multiple files in AWS S3 from terraform

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload, terraform-provider-aws

I want to upload multiple files to AWS S3 from a specific  folder in my local device. I am running into the following error.

[image]

Here is my terraform code.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "testbucket" {
    bucket = "test-terraform-pawan-1"
    acl = "private"

    tags = {
        Name  = "test-terraform"
        Environment = "test"
    }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "uploadfile" {
  bucket = "test-terraform-pawan-1"
  key     = "index.html"
  source = "/home/pawan/Documents/Projects/"

}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[For TF versions < 0.12.8]

You are trying to upload a directory, whereas Terraform expects a single file in the source field. It is not yet supported to upload a folder to an S3 bucket.

However, you can invoke awscli commands using null_resource provisioner, as suggested [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/3020).

```
resource "null_resource" "remove_and_upload_to_s3" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws s3 sync ${path.module}/s3Contents s3://${aws_s3_bucket.site.id}"
  }
}
```

Comment: This wouldnt use the same security creds as running the aws_s3_bucket_object examples.

Comment: It only works once, the first time your run "terraform apply". If you have done that and now you add/modify/delete files from the source, your files won't be synced again on the S3 bucket. This is because the "null_resource" already exists. So this is definitely not a proper solution to this problem.

Answer (score 61):

As of Terraform 0.12.8, you can use the `fileset` function to get a list of files for a given path and pattern. Combined with `for_each`, you should be able to upload every file as its own `aws_s3_bucket_object`:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "dist" {
  for_each = fileset("/home/pawan/Documents/Projects/", "*")

  bucket = "test-terraform-pawan-1"
  key    = each.value
  source = "/home/pawan/Documents/Projects/${each.value}"
  # etag makes the file update when it changes; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107258/terraform-upload-file-to-s3-on-every-apply
  etag   = filemd5("/home/pawan/Documents/Projects/${each.value}")
}
```

See [terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws : aws_s3_bucket_object: support for directory uploads #3020](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/3020) on GitHub.

**Note:** This does not set metadata like `content_type`, and as far as I can tell there is no built-in way for Terraform to infer the content type of a file. This metadata is important for things like HTTP access from the browser working correctly. If that's important to you, you should look into specifying each file manually instead of trying to automatically grab everything out of a folder.

Comment: You can specify the `content_type` via a module: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/dir/template/latest

Comment: @Flair, that is an excellent link! It has a section specific to S3 that directly answers this question. I'd like to leave my answer alone since not everyone will need `content_type`. Could you please quote the S3 example code and link as a separate answer so it is more visible?

Comment: Done! I have even provided a smaller snippet for `.tf.json`.

Comment: Note that `source_hash` is better than `etag` in the case of encryption.

Comment: As of now in 2023 Terraform is encouraging the users to switch to aws_s3_object. "The aws_s3_bucket_object resource is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version!" Can we update this answer?

Answer (score 18):

Since June 9, 2020, terraform has a built-in way to infer the content type (and a few other attributes) of a file which you may need as you upload to a S3 bucket

HCL format:

```hcl
module "template_files" {
  source = "hashicorp/dir/template"

  base_dir = "${path.module}/src"
  template_vars = {
    # Pass in any values that you wish to use in your templates.
    vpc_id = "vpc-abc123"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "static_files" {
  for_each = module.template_files.files

  bucket       = "example"
  key          = each.key
  content_type = each.value.content_type

  # The template_files module guarantees that only one of these two attributes
  # will be set for each file, depending on whether it is an in-memory template
  # rendering result or a static file on disk.
  source  = each.value.source_path
  content = each.value.content

  # Unless the bucket has encryption enabled, the ETag of each object is an
  # MD5 hash of that object.
  etag = each.value.digests.md5
}
```

JSON format:

```json
{
"resource": {
  "aws_s3_bucket_object": {
    "static_files": {
      "for_each": "${module.template_files.files}"
      #...
      }}}}
#...
}
```

Source: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/dir/template/latest

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The [highest vote one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58827910/5668956) doesn't resolve the content file type correctly. Which will cause a problem when trying to serve html file from S3

Answer (score 2):

My objective was to make this dynamic, so whenever i create a folder in a directory, terraform automatically uploads that new folder and its contents into S3 bucket with the same key structure.

Heres how i did it.

First you have to get a local variable with a list of each Folder and the files under it. Then we can loop through that list to upload the source to S3 bucket.

Example: I have a folder called "Directories" with 2 sub folders called "Folder1" and "Folder2" each with their own files.

```
- Directories
  - Folder1
    * test_file_1.txt
    * test_file_2.txt
  - Folder2
    * test_file_3.txt
```

Step 1: Get the local var.

```
locals{
  folder_files = flatten([for d in flatten(fileset("${path.module}/Directories/*", "*")) : trim( d, "../") ])
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
folder_files = [
  "Folder1/test_file_1.txt",
  "Folder1/test_file_2.txt",
  "Folder2/test_file_3.txt",
]
```

Step 2: dynamically upload s3 objects

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "this" {
  for_each = { for idx, file in local.folder_files : idx => file }

  bucket       = aws_s3_bucket.this.bucket
  key          = "/Directories/${each.value}"
  source       = "${path.module}/Directories/${each.value}"
  etag = "${path.module}/Directories/${each.value}"
}
```

This loops over the local var,

So in your S3 bucket, you will have uploaded in the same structure, the local Directory and its sub directories and files:

```
Directory
  - Folder1
    - test_file_1.txt
    - test_file_2.txt
  - Folder2
    - test_file_3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on previous answers, I've tried using [`aws_s3_object`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_object) and didn't find it a good approach for my use-case: building frontend files and uploading them to S3 which is behind cloudfront. To accomplish this, I have to complete 3 things:

1. Build frontend files with updated `.env` file which will contain the endpoint for the api -- (1) I'm not using a custom domain here so I'm using the generated dns name of the elastic load balancer which is unknown to me before the ELB is created.
2. Upload all build files to S3, ensuring correct `content-type`, otherwise, (2) it will automatically upload as octet-stream or something like that which will result to when you visit the website, you will download the html file instead of the browser rendering it.
3. Invalidate cloudfront caches.

The `aws_s3_object` falls short in this use-case for the following reason:

1. `aws_s3_object` doesn't specify the correct content-type, resulting the to side-effect I mentioned above, marked as number 2. To be able to fix this limitation, you'll need to use something like [`terraform-template-dir`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-template-dir).
2. Using `terraform-template-dir` will require that the files already exists before you ran `terraform apply`! Because if they don't, and if they are generated on `terraform apply`, `terraform-template-dir` will not pick up anything, which means you have to run `yarn build` before you run `terraform apply` but then if your `yarn build` depends on your `.env` file which is generated in terraform, you'll have to run build again.
3. You will still need to invalidate cloudfront caches anyway, there are existing modules out there that you can use for this.

I find that the best solution is this:

```
resource "null_resource" "frontend_files" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = timestamp()
  }

  // if we have a local .env file, we want to make sure we keep it before creating a new one with different contents
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
      [[ ! -f ../apps/web/.env ]] || mv ../apps/web/.env ../apps/web/.env.backup
      touch ../apps/web/.env
      echo "VITE_TRPC_ENDPOINT=http://${aws_lb.ecs_lb.dns_name}/trpc" >> ../apps/web/.env
      yarn --cwd ../apps/web build
      aws s3 sync ../apps/web/dist s3://${aws_s3_bucket.frontend_s3_bucket.id}
      aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ${aws_cloudfront_distribution.frontend_cf.id} --paths "/*"
      [[ ! -f ../apps/web/.env.backup ]] || mv ../apps/web/.env.backup ../apps/web/.env
    EOF
  }
}
```

OR the other solution that makes sense is to just put this build process out of terraform to something like a bash script that runs after your terraform build, the down side is that `aws cloudfront create-invalidation` requires your cloudfront id which you wouldn't know how until you've ran `terraform apply`. To workaround this, you can maybe output a file that contains the cloudfront ID and pick up the content of that file in the bash script.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, to upload only the modified files -

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "files_upload" {
  for_each = fileset("${path.root}/dir_upload", "**/*.*")
  bucket      = "bucket-name"
  key         = "key-prefix/${each.value}"
  source      = "${path.root}/dir_upload/${each.value}"
  source_hash = filemd5("${path.root}/dir_upload/${each.value}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works on Terraform v1.6 < without using *dir* templates.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "files" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.buc.bucket

  for_each = fileset("C:\\Users\\terraform-aws\\", "**")
  key=each.key
  
  source = "C:\\Users\\terraform-aws\\${each.value}"
  content_type = each.value
  etag = filemd5("C:\\Users\\terraform-aws\\${each.value}")

}
```

By using **content_type** you can upload html files for static websites.